# Animate Multiple Elements with Scroll Magic & Looping

Tags: javascript, animation, for-loop, custom-data-attribute, scrollmagic

I have a series of divs that I'd like to animate their width from 0% to another % (defined as a data attribute "data-fill") to simulate progress bars. I'm using scroll magic to trigger this animation when the progress bar scrolls into viewport.

I was able to get one to work and then tried to create a for loop to animate all of the divs, but now when I pass in [i] instead of [0] it no longer works. All the console.logging in the world isn't helping I'm getting no console errors.

My JS is:

```
//store all matching divs in an array
var animateProgress = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar-progress");

//loop through array to animate each div 
for (var i = 0; i < animateProgress.length; i++) {
    var animateProgressBar = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar-progress")[i];
    var animPercent = animateProgressBar.getAttribute('data-fill');

   var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
       triggerElement: animateProgressBar, 
       triggerHook: 0.9
   })
   .on("enter", function () {
      // trigger animation by changing inline style.\
      console.log(animPercent);
      animateProgressBar.style.width = animPercent;
    })
   .addIndicators({
      name: "Progress Start"
   })
  .addTo(controller);
}
```

My divs all look the same:

```
<div class="progress-bar-wrap">
   <div class="progress-bar"></div>
   <div data-fill="81%" class="progress-bar-progress"></div>
</div>
```

With the 'progress-bar' and 'progress-bar-progress' both absolutely positioned inside the relatively positioned 'progress-bar-wrap'

If I remove the loop and change i to 0 here: var animateProgressBar = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar-progress")[i]; it works fine for that one div.

I've tried to recreate on plunker here for help debugging: https://plnkr.co/edit/xOo8guXt02ROXnw5PThg

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is possibly the best name for an SO post ever.  Programmers really are mages

Comment: @deltree what does this mean?

Comment: your post is titled "Animate Elements with Scroll Magic"...

Comment: I've added 'looping'. Still not sure what you mean by a SO post or a mage. @deltree

Comment: see https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-9.html#%_chap_1